# Dell XPS 15 L502X monitor light not off when using external monitor

Tags: windows-7, intel-graphics, dell-xps

I mainly use an external monitor (via HDMI) when using my XPS 15 (L502X), however, I noticed an annoying problem when I tried to update the Intel HD 3000 video card driver.

After I started my computer, when the display was switched to external display, the laptop display was supposed to turn off automatically. However, with the new driver, the laptop display was off, but not completely off, it seems the backlight was still on (cannot post images, here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwf8MXlJOZI3djhxeUlmdzA4djQ/view?usp=sharing).

I found out if I switched to the laptop display then back to external, the laptop display was off completely.

The original driver that came with L502X for Windows 7 does not have this issue though. The dell driver for Windows 8 has the problem.

Anyone has any solutions?

Info:
OS: Windows 7, 10 (both have the same symptom)
CPU: i7-2630QM
GPU: GT540M